# How to create a custom authentication?

Tags: quarkus, kong

I am using kong oidc as my reverse proxy to my quarkus application. The user information is stored in a header called "x-userinfo". I would like to take that user information that is stored in a header and "authenticate" the user in quarkus.

I can not find / figure out a way to do this. I would like to do something very similar to what is seen [here](https://github.com/oktadev/okta-kong-origin-example/blob/main/src/main/java/com/okta/examples/originexample/config/RequestContextUser.java).

Comment: I don't have a full answer, but maybe looking at the authorization extensions that already exist might help you. https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/tree/main/extensions/keycloak-authorization

Comment: Not sure to understand your question.
You want to do things on Kong or on your Quarkus application ?

Comment: I ended up creating a custom quarkus [authentication mechanism](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-customization). My question was worded poorly but I wanted to retrieve a base64 token that contained the users credentials in a json format and assign the values to the SecurityIdentity.